# StormCrawler do action when crawling one domain finished

Tags: java, web-crawler, stormcrawler

I want to do an action (in my case send a tuple to one bolt) when the crawler finished crawling one domain.

I saw that StormCrawler is able to do even revisit a website after a given interval. In which component or how could I see when one domain is finished crawling in the scenario of crawling multiple domains simultaneously?

My current setup is using StormCrawler with Elasticsearch and Kibana.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented a [custom Bolt](https://github.com/HPI-BP2017N2/Crawler/blob/master/src/main/java/de/hpi/bpStormcrawler/BPFinishedDomainBolt.java) which follows the former approach but could also be extended or modified for the second approach mentioned in the answer of Julien Nioche

Answer (score 1):

See "When do I know when a crawl is finished?" in [FAQ](http://stormcrawler.net/faq/).

> I saw that StormCrawler is able to do even revisit a website after a
>   given interval.

StormCrawler does not schedule websites as such but individual URLs.

> In which component or how could I see when one domain is finished
>   crawling in the scenario of crawling multiple domains simultaneously?

Depending on the number of sites that you are crawling, you could write a custom bolt which would query ES for all the hostnames in the status index and detect those which have no more urls with a status of DISCOVERED.

Alternatively, a custom bolt which would track the sites you are crawling and trigger an action whenever no url for a particular site has been fetched in the last N minutes.

Comment: To the first approach:
A query at regular intervals would then use the AbstractSpout or AggregationSpout as it gets no tuples as input but rather just outputs tuples when a host without any DISCOVERED URL is discovered?

Comment: You don't need to get a tuple as input - just set up a tick tuple on the custom bolt - see https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/external/elasticsearch/src/main/java/com/digitalpebble/stormcrawler/elasticsearch/metrics/StatusMetricsBolt.java for an example. The problem with that approach is that you'd need to track which hosts you already flagged as finished. The second approach doesn't have that problem and doesn't require expensive Es queries but has the limitation that if the worker restarts, you'd lose the info about which hosts were last fetched.